# Цвет кнопок не меняется

Tags: android, button

Всем привет! Создаю кнопки, и по умолчанию выходит один цвет (любой), который совсем не меняется. В коде добавляю любой цвет, но на деле так и остаётся синим.

[image]

Comment: Приведите код, пожалуйста, чтобы было с чем работать :)

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="50dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#0094FF" />
    <solid android:color="#F79423"/>
</shape>

Comment: Приводите код в вопросе, через правку оного. В комментах код теряет форматирование. Также покажите где и как вы используете тот код, что уже привели - может вы его нигде не применяете?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете библиотеку поддержки API 22 и больше, то вы можете использовать `android:backgroundTint`.
Также вы можете создать отдельную тему для вашей кнопки. Для этого в папке values создаете ресурс.[image]

Дальше вставляете этот код

`<resources> <style name="Имя вашей темы" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar"> <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item> <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item> <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item> </style> </resources>`

Здесь colorPrimary будет отвечать за цвет кнопки, ColorPrimaryVariant - тональность основного цвета и ColorOnPrimary - Цвет, который соответствует рекомендациям по доступности для текста / значков при рисовании поверх основного цвета.
После чего в xml коде внутри Button меняете тему для кнопки

```
android:theme="Имя вашей темы"
```